# video can not be accessed outside the application

Tags: android

I am developing an application where downloaded video can not be accessed by user outside the app. I want to know how to make it possible that user can not accessed video outside the app and only play it in the app. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes it's possible to do so** infact popular apps like youtube do it when you download a video for offline loading. you have to encrypt the video and delete the original. After doing that decode it back when you want to play